# Symfony2 form choice - array of objects (not mapped entities)

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I have an array of objects:

```
[0] ProductObject
         Title
         Image
         Link

[1] ProductObject
         Title
         Image
         Link
```

etc.

I can pass these objects in fine to my form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add(
                'products',
                'choice',
                array(
                        'choices'   => $productsArray,
                        'multiple'  => false,
                        'required' => false
                )
        );

    }
```

Then in the template:

```
            {{ form_label(form.products, 'products') }}
            {{ form_errors(form.products) }}
            {{ form_widget(form.products) }}

            {{ form_rest(form) }}
```

Now , as expected, the form renders out like:

```
<optgroup label="0">
    <option value="id">174</option>
    <option value="title">A Bag Of Frogs</option>
    <option value="image">Image</option>
    <option value="link">http://www.myshoppe.com</option>
</optgroup>
```

I only wish to have the title in the dropdown, but I'd ideally like to keep the image and link available as I want to use javascript to populate another div with the image title and link as soon as the user selects a product.

So , the question is "how can I hide object properties within Twig?"

or

Is this ludicrous?

:)

Answer (score 5):

I think you are looking for [ObjectChoiceList](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/ChoiceList/ObjectChoiceList.php).

You could use it like this:

```
$choiceList = new ObjectChoiceList($products, 'title', array(), null, 'id');

public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add(
            'products',
            'choice',
            array(
                    'choice_list'   => $choiceList,
                    'multiple'  => false,
                    'required' => false
            )
    );

}
```